# Building a regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

How to check the following text in C# with Regex:

```
key_in-get { 43243225543543543 };

or

key_in_set { password123 : 34980430943834 };
```

I tried to build a regular expression, but I failed after few hours.

Here is my code:

```
string text1 = "key_in-get { 322389238237 };";
string text2 = "key_in-set { password123 : 322389238237 };";

string pattern = "key_in-(get|set) { .* };";

var result1 = Regex.IsMatch(text, pattern);
Console.Write("Is valid: {0} ", result1);

var result2 = Regex.IsMatch(text, pattern);
Console.Write("Is valid: {0} ", result2);
```

I have to check if there is "set" or "get".

If the pattern finds "set" then it can only accept following pattern "text123 : 123456789", and if it finds "get" then should accept only "123456789".

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your problem. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ks4vhn

Comment: Note that curly brackets (`{` and `}`) have a special meaning in a regular expression, so they need escaping with backslashes, as `\{` and `\}`.

Comment: If you're trying to match different things based on "set" or "get", how about using two different patterns, one for "get" and one for "set"?

Comment: @AdrianHHH There is [**no need escaping `{` and `}`**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=key_in-%28get%7cset%29+%7b+.*+%7d%3b&i=key_in-get+%7b+322389238237+%7d%3b%0d%0akey_in-set+%7b+password123+%3a+322389238237+%7d%3b) here.

Comment: Try `key_in-(?:get|(set)) {(?(1) \w+ :) \w+ };`, see [the demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=key_in-%28%3f%3aget%7c%28set%29%29+%7b%28%3f%281%29+%5cw%2b+%3a%29+%5cw%2b+%7d%3b&i=key_in-get+%7b+322389238237+%7d%3b%0d%0akey_in-set+%7b+password123+%3a+322389238237+%7d%3b%0d%0akey_in-set+%7b+322389238237+%7d%3b%0d%0akey_in-get+%7b+password123+%3a+322389238237+%7d%3b). Or, ``key_in-(?:get|(set)) {(?(1) \w+ :) \d+ };``. If the whole string must match, add `^` at the start and `$` at the end.

Comment: Are you _extracting_ information with this regex, or _validating_ a string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please check the second bullet in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-escapes-in-regular-expressions which discusses curly brackets.

Comment: @AdrianHHH See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66824150/building-a-regular-expression-in-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment118123767_66824150).

Comment: AdrianHHH is saying there's something special about c#'s curly brace in regex. I think the point is that you could have `{2}` for example in the pattern, which would mean "2 of the previous token". `\{2\}` would be the proper way to escape it. I think in this case it's not needed because there are spaces within the braces, and it's not a  number.

Comment: Some quick experiments with VS2019 seem to confirm @gunr2171's latest comment. Using a re with spaces within the curly braces suppresses their use as a quantifier. What a wierd regex language quirk, I was expecting to get a run-time regex exception.

Comment: Programming languages are just swell, ain't they? But I'm glad that's solved.

Comment: Your example text has a hyphen before `get` but an unerscore before `set`. Your pattern uses a hyphen for both, just checking that it's really not the case the symbol is different

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```cs
key_in-(?:get|(set)) {(?(1) \w+ :) \w+ };
key_in-(?:get|(set))\s*{(?(1)\s*\w+\s*:)\s*\w+\s*};
key_in-(?:get|(set))\s*{(?(1)\s*\w+\s*:)\s*\d+\s*};
```

See [the regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=key_in-%28%3F%3Aget%7C%28set%29%29%20%7B%28%3F%281%29%20%5Cw%2B%20%3A%29%20%5Cw%2B%20%7D%3B&i=key_in-get%20%7B%20322389238237%20%7D%3B%0D%0Akey_in-set%20%7B%20password123%20%3A%20322389238237%20%7D%3B%0D%0Akey_in-set%20%7B%20322389238237%20%7D%3B%0D%0Akey_in-get%20%7B%20password123%20%3A%20322389238237%20%7D%3B). The second one allows any amount of any whitespace between the elements and the third one allows only digits after `:` or as part of the `get` expression.

If the whole string must match, add `^` at the start and `$` at the end of the pattern.

*Details*:

- `key_in-` - a substring
- `(?:get|(set))` - `get` or `set` (the latter is captured into Group 1)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `{` - a `{` char
- `(?(1)\s*\w+\s*:)` - a conditional construct: if Group 1 matched, match one or more word chars enclosed with zero or more whitespaces and then a colon
- `\s*\w+\s*` - one or more word chars enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `};` - a literal substring.

Answer (score 0):

In the pattern that you tried `key_in-(get|set) { .* };` you are matching either get or set followed by { until the last occurrence of } which could possibly also match `key_in-get { }; };`

As an alternative solution, you could use an alternation `|` specifying each of the accepted parts for the get and the set.

```
key_in-(?:get\s*{\s*\w+|set\s*{\s*\w+\s*:\s*\w+)\s*};
```

The pattern matches

- `key_in-` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `get\s*{\s*\w+` Match get, `{` between optional whitespace chars and 1+ word chars
  - `|` Or
  - `set\s*{\s*\w+\s*:\s*\w+` Match set, `{` between optional whitespace chars and word chars on either side with `:` in between.
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\s*};` Match optional whitespace chars and `};`

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=key_in-%28%3f%3aget%5cs*%7b%5cs*%5cw%2b%7cset%5cs*%7b%5cs*%5cw%2b%5cs*%3a%5cs*%5cw%2b%29%5cs*%7d%3b&i=key_in-get+%7b+322389238237+%7d%3b%0d%0akey_in-set+%7b+password123+%3a+322389238237+%7d%3b%0d%0akey_in-set+%7b+322389238237+%7d%3b%0d%0akey_in-get+%7b+password123+%3a+322389238237+%7d%3b)